# Оставить в строке только указанные html тэги, и атрибуты

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Такой вопрос.

Есть пользователи, и хочу дать им возможность использовать html-тэги, для красоты сообщений, но есть хитрожопые юзеры, которые в атрибуты тегов могут подставить атрибут события, и все, беда.

Есть, к примеру, строка:

```
<span style="color:#cc0000" id="id">Текст</span>
```

Как мне из этой строки, сохранить тэг только с атрибутом style?

Пробовал написать что-то вроде такой функции

```
function cutTags( $str, $tags = [] ){
    $not_cut_tags = '';

    // Собираем массив тегов, которые вырехать не нужно
    foreach ($tags as $tag_name => $tag_attrs) {
        $not_cut_tags .= "<$tag_name>";
    }

    // Вырезаем теги, но оставляем те которые не нужно резать
    $str = strip_tags($str, $not_cut_tags);

    // Здесь мы убираем ненужные атрибуты в оставшейся строке
    foreach ($tags as $tag => $attrs) {

        if( is_array($attrs) ){
            // Если есть атрибуты - делаем regex строку
            foreach ($attrs as $attribute) {
                $search_attrs .= "\s" . "$attribute=\"([^\"]+)\"|\s";
            }

            preg_match_all( '/'.$search_attrs.'/', $str, $m);
            $m =    implode(' ', $m[0]);

            $r_from     = "<{$tag}[^>]+>";
            $r_to       = "<$tag $m>";
        }else{
            // Атрибутов нет - просто заменяем тэг <tag ....> на <tag>
            $r_from     = "<{$tag}[^>]+>";
            $r_to       = "<$tag>";
        }
        $str        = preg_replace("/".$r_from."/i", $r_to, $str);
    }

    return $str;
}

$str    = '<p><span style="color:#2980b9"><a href="">Ссылка в спане</a></span></p>';

$tags   = [
    'span' => ['style'],
    'a'     => ['href'],
];
```

Вроде бы работает, но случается косяк, вот как в примере. Атрибут style есть у , а он дается еще и ссылке .. Сижу уже несколько часов, голова не варит... Может, есть какие-то готовые скрипты или решения?

Спасибо!!!

Comment: Возможно, jevix

Comment: @andreymal читаю сейчас, вроде бы оно!

Comment: @user190134 а **[регуляркой](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ee0bc8808713710682064555cdd8e39d628b0ab)** не проще?

Comment: http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: @andreymal что-то не получается регуляркой

Comment: @Эдуард да, у Вас в примере спан заменяет ок все, но A пропускает, вместе с аттрибутами

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека [Jevix](https://github.com/ur001/Jevix/) Идеально подошла

Пример использования
 $jevix = new Jevix();

```
//Конфигурация

// Устанавливаем разрешённые теги. (Все не разрешенные теги считаются запрещенными.)
$jevix->cfgAllowTags(array('a', 'img', 'strong', 'ul', 'li', 'h1', 'h2'));

// Устанавливаем разрешённые параметры тегов.
$jevix->cfgAllowTagParams('a', array('title', 'href'));

// Устанавливаем параметры тегов являющиеся обязяательными. Без них вырезает тег оставляя содержимое.
$jevix->cfgSetTagParamsRequired('a', 'href');

// Устанавливаем теги которые может содержать тег контейнер
$jevix->cfgSetTagChilds('ul', 'li', true, false);

// Устанавливаем атрибуты тегов, которые будут добавлятся автоматически
$jevix->cfgSetTagParamsAutoAdd('a', array('rel' => 'nofollow'));

//Парсинг
$res = $jevix->parse('...тут...мог...бы...быть...ваш...текст...');
?>
```