# Регулярное выражения для удаления атрибутов у тегов кроме определенных

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет. Регулярки для меня - тёмный лес. И сколько бы я не пытался понять принцип их действия - так ничего и  не вышло. Вобщем нужно составить регулярку для удаления всех атрибутов тегов кроме определенных. Например есть строка

```
$string = '<a href="site.com" height="150" width="30" style="display:block" class="visible">ссылка</a>';
```

нужно удалить из неё все атрибуты кроме `href` одной регуляркой. Возможно ли это? Может быть у кого-то есть готовое выражение для этого?

Comment: а воспользуйтесь html парсером, там за вас все написали

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/771764/186083

Comment: мне нужно только в одном месте удалить все атрибуты кроме одного. не думаю что для этого уместно подключать какие-либо библиотеки

Comment: Ну  DOMDocument входит в состав самого языка. Что бы все не удалять, можно создать новый тег и перенести в него только href и содержимое тега

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С точки зрения правильного решения, безусловно надо использовать `DOMDocument::loadHTML`, но если нет времени/желания копаться, то можно [использовать код](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/997470c77e6a14f2b2c65686ff04e65b9b855f6e):

```
<?php
$string = '<a href="site.com" height="150" width="30" style="display:block" class="visible">ссылка</a>';
$string = preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)(?:[^>]*(\shref=['\"][^'\"]*['\"]))?[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2$3>', $string);
echo $string;
```