# Вырезать все теги iframe и img

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В данный момент получилось только находить теги img

```
<?php $content = preg_replace('/<img(?:\\s[^<>]*)?>/i', '', content(50)); ?>
```

Comment: [Посмотрите тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/771764/213987). Многим новичкам кажется, что регулярки для задач, подобных вашей это идеальный инструмент, но на самом деле - нет. Используйте библиотеки работы с DOM, код будет чище, проще, нагляднее.

Comment: на всякий случай, напомню про `strip_tags`

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю.

Comment: Если нет вложенных тегов `iframe`, то `'~<iframe\b[^>]*>.*?</iframe>~is'`